# Should Huffman compression be in strict order of frequency?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

I'm just testing where I've got to on a Huffman encoding exercise. My test file has a lot of low frequency chars (mostly frequency of 1) and a low number of high frequency chars. I'm testing what's being read off the encoding tree; it seems that a char with a frequency of 19 has 6 bits, a char with a frequency of 10 has 3 bits, and a char with a frequency of 5 has 5 bits. Is this sort of anomaly to be expected or should they always be in exactly the right order?

Comment: Shouldn't the high-freq characters consume less bits rather than more?

Comment: Right- it does seem like quite a big difference. 19 must be quite alot further down the tree than 10. Must be something to do with how the non-leaf nodes are being created or are coming off..

Comment: It's generally right. All the low frequency chars have higher numbers of bits. There's just a couple of these types of anomoly near the top...

Comment: I would say it's a bug in your program. To my knowledge, Huffman encoding shouldn't have this problem. High frequency characters should always consume less bits. There are proofs of this, [here's one](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~brudno/csc373w09/huffman.pdf).

Comment: Yes, it is, I'm creating the for loop with the size of the queue, which is getting smaller as it builds the tree. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your implementation.  It possible to have a wide range of frequencies with the same bit length, but the bit lengths should never be reversed with respect to the frequencies.